# clrDgSingleSelected is throwing error in clarity version 3

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am creating a Datagrid with single selection option using Clarity version 3 and Angular 9.
but this is throwing error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined
 at Selection.isLocked (clr-angular.js:11557)..." in @clr/angular library and datagrid is not rendered.
Below is code snippet:
app.component.html

```
  <clr-datagrid [(clrDgSingleSelected)]="selectedUser" [clrDgRowSelection]="true">
   <clr-dg-column>User ID</clr-dg-column>  
   <clr-dg-column>Name</clr-dg-column>
   <clr-dg-column>Favorite color</clr-dg-column>
   <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users" [clrDgItem]="user">
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.id}}</clr-dg-cell>
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.color}}</clr-dg-cell>
   </clr-dg-row> 
   <clr-dg-footer>{{users.length}} users</clr-dg-footer>
  </clr-datagrid>`
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'ang9VMC3POC';`
  users = [{
     id:"1",
     name:"test1",
    color:"red"
 },
{
 id:"2",
 name:"test2",
 color:"blue"
},
{
 id:"3",
 name:"test3",
 color:"green"
},
];
selectedUser = this.users[2];
}
```

Comment: any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, it is helpful to make a Stackblitz demo to see the behavior, it is hard to guess otherwise what the exact error might be. https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team has starters.

Comment: here is the link for the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v3-light-theme-dkbmev

Answer (score 0):

You are using *ngFor while you should use *clrDgItems. So your code would look something like:

```
<clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users" [clrDgItem]="user">
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.id}}</clr-dg-cell>
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
     <clr-dg-cell>{{user.color}}</clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
```

here is a link for the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v3-light-theme-o5grmz